# how can I get layout like added image?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext

[image]

Hello, I want to add an input to add a location. Here in image, when we click on particular layout its directed to another activity where the locations are available and when the location is selected it gets added to this layout, as shown here GangM. I am unable to understand what kind of view it is? I tried to add edit text view. Is is the same? And how can I get navigation arrow above edit text view??

How can I get this arrow over edit text view???

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableRow with weight=1>
 <ImageView icon location with layout_weight=.2>
 <EditText with layout_weight=.8 and         
           android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow">
 </TableRow>
```

Comment: can I do this with edittext view?? how can I get arrow over edittext view>

Comment: what action do you want to perform with arrow?

Comment: No action , Just want to add to show navigation. Action I can do with edittext right??

Comment: Pleasure... accepting the answer is a good way to say thanks :) .

Answer (score -1):

Lets suppose u have three activity Activity1, Activity 2, Activity 3.
Consider the screen u r showing in figure as Activity 2.

First transfer, a Bundle data (from = "") to activity 2.
Display the bundle data from previous activity.

Second, when user click on edit text on Activity 2. Delete activity 2 and move to activity 3. Let user select the location in activity 3. Now delete or finish the activity 3 and pass the bundle data (from = "GangM") from activity 3 to activity 2.
In this way, selected location can be taken back to current activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its useful. But my confusion is is it a text view or image view??

Comment: Text View is better when u have random text or location to display, but image view is helpful when u have fixed location or text.